# Failed invoking server hub method

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, signalr

I am trying to get basic signalR connectivity going between my react application and a server component written in C#.

I have bootstrapped the signalR client using the JQuery SignalR library and invoking as middleware. On start up, it should try and call the only server method available, which should then cause the hub to be constructed and the method called. However the constructor for the hub doesn't get called, nor does the invoked method. Based on the client connection properties, it is clearly finding the hub and connecting as the onStateChanged() method gets called with "Connected" as the new state, and I can view the connection object in chrome dev tools. However when invoking the server method, it simply gives me the following error in the javascript console (nothing happens on the server process at all)

> jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4 POST
>   https://localhost:3830/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAuw4b0U8E80ynfN6Njj7iGAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAC2F%2BIFF73jLL%2FLtWBjkBafAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAIKqx8wP6asrIYRF24wgF%2FwwAAAAJLyt3OCdy%2FIXbOYlu1vSNKLkF%2Fs19QM9yVQb%2FhpfVxavZSxG7uauwc3vXSfZYDFrFAAAAMzCxkLJZxDevB1J8Wqst8IUk0Al&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22logtailhub%22%7D%5D
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

The more detailed SignalR error is

> Error: Send failed.↵    at Object.error
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8:4512)↵
>   at Object.transportError
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8:4627)↵
>   at s
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8:18349)↵
>   at Object.error
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8:18693)↵
>   at i
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:27451)↵ 
>   at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith]
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:28215)↵ 
>   at y
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4:22617)↵ 
>   at XMLHttpRequest.c
>   (https://localhost:3830/assets/signalr/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4:26750

In the below code, I break on the line

```
const sessionHub = connection[HUB_NAME];
```

Which then lets me view the connection for that particular hub, which is connected and seems fine. But on the following invoke line it fails with the above error.

My client middleware code

```
import hostlookup from "./hostlookup";
import { LOGTAIL_INCOMING_METHOD_UPDATED, HUB_NAME, SIGNALR_CONNECT, SIGNALR_DISCONNECT, LOGTAIL_ACTION_START, LOGTAIL_ACTION_STOP, LOGTAIL_SERVER_METHOD_STOP, LOGTAIL_SERVER_METHOD_START, SIGNALR_STATE_DISCONNECTED, SIGNALR_STATE_CONNECTING, SIGNALR_STATE_RECONNECTING } from "./constants";
import { getSignalRStatusChangedAction, getSignalRStopAction } from "./actions";
import { getLogTailUpdatedAction } from "../../modules/logtail/actions";

const url = hostlookup().host + '/signalr';
const connection = $.hubConnection(url, {
    useDefaultPath: false
});

export default function createSignalrMiddleware() {
    return (store) => {
        const dispatch = store.dispatch.bind(store);

        const SIGNALR_STATES = {
            0: 'Connecting',
            1: 'Connected',
            2: 'Reconnecting',
            4: 'Disconnected'
        };

        let keepAlive = true;
        let wasConnected = false;
        let currentState = null;

        initialiseListeners(dispatch);

        function onStateChanged(state) {
            if (currentState === state) { return; }

            if (currentState === 2 && state === 1) {
                connection.start().done(() => {
                    // reconnect actions if required
                });
            }

            currentState = state;
            dispatch(getSignalRStatusChangedAction(state));
        }

        connection.stateChanged((state) => {
            const newStateName = SIGNALR_STATES[state.newState];

            if (newStateName === 'Connected') {
                wasConnected = true;
            }

            onStateChanged(state.newState);
        });

        connection.disconnected(() => {
            if (keepAlive) {
                if (wasConnected) {
                    onStateChanged(SIGNALR_STATE_RECONNECTING);
                } else {
                    onStateChanged(SIGNALR_STATE_CONNECTING);
                }

                connection.start().done(() => {
                    // Connect actions if required
                });
            }
        });

        function initialiseListeners(dispatcher) {
            const sessionHub = connection[HUB_NAME] = connection.createHubProxy(HUB_NAME);

            sessionHub.on(LOGTAIL_INCOMING_METHOD_UPDATED,
                (logDataLine) => {
                    dispatch(getLogTailUpdatedAction(logDataLine));
                })

            sessionHub.on('Disconnect', () => dispatcher(getSignalRStopAction()));
        }

        return (next) => (action) => {
            const { type } = action;
            const sessionHub = connection[HUB_NAME];

            switch (type) {
                case SIGNALR_CONNECT:
                    keepAlive = true;
                    onStateChanged(SIGNALR_STATE_CONNECTING);
                    connection.start().done(() => {
                        const sessionHub = connection[HUB_NAME];
                        sessionHub.invoke(LOGTAIL_SERVER_METHOD_START, 'test')
                        // Connect actions if required
                    });
                    return;

                case SIGNALR_DISCONNECT:
                    keepAlive = false;
                    wasConnected = false;
                    onStateChanged(SIGNALR_STATE_DISCONNECTED);
                    connection.stop();
                    return;

                case LOGTAIL_ACTION_START:
                    sessionHub.invoke(LOGTAIL_SERVER_METHOD_START, action.applicationName);
                    return;

                case LOGTAIL_ACTION_STOP:
                    sessionHub.invoke(LOGTAIL_SERVER_METHOD_STOP);
                    return;

                default:
                    return next(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My server hub code

```
    public interface ILogTailClient
    {
        void LogDataUpdated(string[] logData);        
    }

    [Authorize]
    public class LogTailHub : Hub<ILogTailClient>
    {
        private readonly IClientConnectionHandler _clientConnectionHandler;
        private readonly IAuthorisedUserCache _userCache;
        private readonly ILogTailService _logTailService;

        public LogTailHub(IClientConnectionHandler clientConnectionHandler, IAuthorisedUserCache userCache, ILogTailService logTailService)
        {
            _clientConnectionHandler = clientConnectionHandler;
            _userCache = userCache;
            _logTailService = logTailService;
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var clientConnection = GetClientConnection();
            if (clientConnection != null)
                _clientConnectionHandler.OnConnected(clientConnection);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            lock (_clientConnectionHandler)
            {
                _clientConnectionHandler.OnDisconnected(Context.ConnectionId);

                var clientConnection = GetClientConnection();
                if (clientConnection != null)
                    _clientConnectionHandler.OnConnected(clientConnection);
            }

            return base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            _clientConnectionHandler.OnDisconnected(Context.ConnectionId);            
            StopTailing();
            await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }

        public void StartTailing(string applicationName)
        {
            _logTailService.StartListening(Context.ConnectionId, applicationName);
        }

        public void StopTailing()
        {
            _logTailService.StopListening(Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        private IClientConnection GetClientConnection()
        {
            if (Context.User != null && _userCache.TryGetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name, out var authorisedUser))
            {
                return new ClientConnection(Context.ConnectionId, authorisedUser);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The DI registration for the hub

```
public class WebNotificationsModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .Except<LogTailHub>()          // Defined below
                .Except<HubContextProvider>();  // Defined as Singleton below

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = false,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };
            builder.Register(ctx => hubConfiguration);

            builder.Register(ctx => {
                var connectionManager = hubConfiguration.Resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
                return connectionManager.GetHubContext<LogTailHub, ILogTailClient>();
            }).ExternallyOwned();

            builder.RegisterType<HubContextProvider>().As<IHubContextProvider>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<LogTailHub>().ExternallyOwned(); // SignalR hub registration

            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            builder.RegisterInstance(serializer).As<JsonSerializer>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The server side code SignalR is calling is throwing an exception, you need the details of this exception to point you to where your code is falling over. The details should be in your server event log. Alternatively you can (temporarily) turn on detailed errors which will push the exception detail into the JavaScript console.

In Startup.cs:

hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.huboptions.enabledetailederrors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

If you go this route be sure to turn off detailed errors before deploying.

Comment: Its already actually enabled - see my above code for the DI registration it has turned on detailed errors - and all I get back in the error object is "Send failed". I tried to enable all .NET errors in the debug console (Im running server process locally so can step through that too) but nothing throws an exception in that IDE

Comment: Sorry I missed that, have you tried turning on connection logging? This should give you a bit more detail on what the browser thinks the problem is. $.connection.hub.logging = true; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#MonitoringTransports

Comment: is $.connection.hub equivalent to my 'connection' variable above - const connection = $.hubConnection(url, {
    useDefaultPath: false
});

Comment: Also is there a way I can test my hub using Postman or something like that? Or does it have to be through a specific signalr client?

Comment: yes that the javascript connection object. I create my connection in a slightly different way to yours so I'm not 100% on the syntax you might find `$.hubConnection(url, {useDefaultPath: false, logging: false});` works. Or declaring it as a var and having `connection.logging = true;` as the next line. I don't know about testing with 3rd party tools.

Comment: Simplified as much as possible since my code connects to multiple hubs here is the logging code using the syntax I'm familiar with `var connections = new Array();
connections.push($.hubConnection("https://www.someurl.com/"));
var proxies = connections[0].createHubProxies();
connections[0].logging = true;
connections[0].start();`